# How can I get a Clip object for a ClipLauncherSlot?

Tags: bitwig-api

I have a `ClipLauncherSlot` in Bitwig API, and I'd like to get ahold of the Clip within it so I can transpose it on user input.

The docs aren't online that I know of, so I can't link to them.  But extensive searching has yielding absolutely no way of getting ahold of `Clip` objects in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're supposed to work with a CursorClip.

Instead of directly accessing the clip, you access it through a CursorClip. The CursorClip will follow your selection and always represent the currently selected clip.

Something like this:

```
CursorClip cursorClip = host.createLauncherCursorClip()
clipLauncherSlot.select()
// Now your cursorClips represents the desired clip.
cursorClip.transpose()
```

Not entirely sure about the exact implementation, maybe you have to do some additonal steps for the cursor to correctly follow, but something like this should work.

See also here: https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=550738 for a similar problem. They had some problems with execution time, keep that in mind if you run into unexpected behaviour.